# Finding the polar line of the intersection of a polar line and a tangent

Tags: geometry, inversive-geometry

Let $K$ be an inversion circle with center $O$ and let $C$ be the point of intersection of two lines tangent to $K$ in $A$ and $B$. Then let $E$ be the intersection of the line $AB$ and the line tangent to $K$ in another point $D$. 
Prove that the line $CD$ is the polar to $E$.

[image: Figure]

So I know that the intersection between $AB$ and $OC$ is the inverse point of $C$, so I think I have to use that in order to find another point $F$ in $K$ such that $FE$ is tangent to $K$, therefore the intersection between $DF$ and $OE$ is the inverse point of $E$. However, from there I don't know how to relate both ideas in order to get that $D$, $F$ and $C$ are collinear. Any help?

Comment: Coming from a background of projective geometry, I'd tackle this by observing that $(A,B;D,F)$ form a harmonic set on $K$, i.e. the lines connecting these to any other point on $K$ have cross ratio $-1$. This in turn relates to the fact that $(A,A;B,B;D,F)$ form a quadrilateral set, as evidenced by the lines $AA$ (i.e. the tangent in $A$), $BB$ and $DF$ meeting in $C$. Likewise $(D,D;F,F;A,B)$ form a quadrilateral set, and the concurrence in $E$ is the evidence. A quadrilateral set where two points occur doubled like this is a harmonic set, and there order doesn't matter as much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fact that [reciprocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_and_polar) (exchanging poles and polars) preserves incidence. If a point is incident with a line, then the polar line of that point is incident with the pole of the line. If three lines are concurrent (i.e. meet in a point) then their poles are collinear.

Writing $t_A$ for the tangent in $A$, you start by observing that $t_A, t_B, CD$ meet in $C$. So reciprocate them all and you know that $A$, $B$ and the pole of $CD$ are collinear. So the pole of $CD$ must lie on $AB$ (as we just showed) and on $t_D$ (since that is part of the classical construction of a pole), so it is in fact the point $E$.

Comment: Thanks, that seems clear :)